# Search for and Copy Worksheets from one Workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook (wb1) which contains the macro. I open a file (wb) by selecting it in a msgbox.

I want to loop through all sheets of wb and if sheet.name like "*xxx*" save a copy of the sheet in wb1 before the first sheet.

```
Sub GetFile()

    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As ThisWorkbook

    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*", _
      Title:="Sélectionner le fichier des extractions Magnitude sur la Phase IAS CONSO")

    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

    For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets

        If LCase(Sheet.Name) Like "*Sheet1*" Then
            Range("A2").Select
            'ActiveSheet.Delete
        End If

    Next Sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFile()
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files (.),.", Title:="Sélectionner le fichier des extractions Magnitude sur la Phase IAS CONSO")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
    For Each sht In wb.Sheets
        If LCase(sht.Name) Like "*sheet1*" Then sht.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next sht
    wb.Close False '<--| close the newly opened workbook without saving it
End Sub
```

also note I changed:

```
If LCase(sht.Name) Like "*Sheet1*"
```

to:

```
If LCase(sht.Name) Like "*sheet1*"
```

otherwise the check would never return `True` since it'd compare an all lowercase characters string (`LCase(sht.Name)`) to a string with one uppercase character ("S")

Comment: and just for my knowledge :if i want to copy before .... but values only - which code i need to use on this lign ?                                                             Then sht.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Comment: you can't do that  _during_ the `Copy()` method. you have to act either on copied (before the `Copy()` method) or pasted (after the `Copy()` method) sheet. BTW you my want to accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to accept my answer. Thank you!